# pyparsing how to use infixNotation for representing iif(cond, if true, if false)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I need to parse this using pyparsing: `iif(condition,value if true,value if false)`, but this kind of ternary comparisson shall have another comparisson, I mean:

```
`iif(iif(condition1,value1,value2)>iif(condition2,value1,value2),value3,value4)`
```

I found this:

```
integer = Word(nums)
variable = Word(alphas, alphanums)
boolLiteral = oneOf("true false")
operand = boolLiteral | variable | integer
comparison_op = oneOf("== <= >= != < >")
QM,COLON = map(Literal,"?:")
expr = infixNotation(operand,
    [
    (comparison_op, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ((QM,COLON), 3, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ])
```

which is able to parse this:
`expr.parseString("(x==1? true: (y == 10? 100 : 200) )")`

but I was unable to modify this code to fit my needs. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Mr. Paul I came up with this solution:

```
arith_expr = Forward()

iif = CaselessKeyword("iif")
    open = Literal("(")
    close = Literal(")")

    var_name = pyparsing_common.identifier()
    fn_call = Group(iif + open - Group(Optional(delimitedList(arith_expr))) + close)
    arith_operand = fn_call | num

    rel_comparison_operator = oneOf("< > <= >=")
    eq_comparison_operator = oneOf("== !=")
    plus_minus_operator = oneOf("+ -")
    mult_div_operator = oneOf("* / %")

    arith_expr <<= infixNotation(arith_operand,
                                    [
                                        # add other operators here - in descending order of precedence
                                        # http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm
                                        ('-', 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
                                        (mult_div_operator, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                        (plus_minus_operator, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                        (rel_comparison_operator, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                        (eq_comparison_operator, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                    ]
                                    )
```

I'm using some of my previous rules. Now I'm voting to close this post.

Comment: `iif` isn't an infix operator. It has the same syntax as a function call, so you should look at examples of how to parse function calls, not at examples of how to parse `? :`.

Comment: @sepp2k I didn't get what you mean

Comment: I meant that a) `iif` is not an infix operator (i.e. an operator that appears between its operands) and b) the syntax for `iif` is `iif(foo, bar, baz)`, which is very similar to the syntax of function calls (and not at all similar to the syntax `foo ? bar : baz`).

Comment: The ternary operation `?:` is "infix" because the operators are *in-between* the operands -> `cond_value ? true_value : false_value`. In contrast,  `iif(cond_value, true_value, false_value)` is just a function call, calling the `iif` function with 3 arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sepp2k mentions in his comment, the string you are trying to parse *isn't* infix notation, although you may end up using as an operand in infix notation. And the arguments you pass to `iif` may themselves be infix notation expressions. So infix notation will definitely be part of this parser, but it won't be the part that parses your `iif` function call.

Here is how the function call would look in pyparsing:

```
fn_call = pp.Group(var_name + LPAREN - pp.Group(pp.Optional(pp.delimitedList(arith_expr))) + RPAREN)
```

The operands you use to define an arithmetic expression could themselves include a function call, so the parser's recursion will require you to use pyparsing's Forward class.

```
arith_expr = pp.Forward()
```

This will allow you to use `arith_expr` in other sub-expressions (like we just did in fn_call) before we have fully defined just what `arith_expr` looks like.

Cutting to the chase, here is a minimal parser to parse your `iif` function:

```
import pyparsing as pp

# for recursive infix notations, or those with many precedence levels, it is best to enable packrat parsing
pp.ParserElement.enablePackrat()
LPAREN, RPAREN = map(pp.Suppress, "()")

arith_expr= pp.Forward()

var_name = pp.pyparsing_common.identifier()
integer = pp.pyparsing_common.integer()
fn_call = pp.Group(var_name + LPAREN - pp.Group(pp.Optional(pp.delimitedList(arith_expr))) + RPAREN)
arith_operand = fn_call | var_name | integer

rel_comparison_operator = pp.oneOf("< > <= >=")
eq_comparison_operator = pp.oneOf("== !=")
plus_minus_operator = pp.oneOf("+ -")
mult_div_operator = pp.oneOf("* / %")

arith_expr <<= pp.infixNotation(arith_operand,
                                [
                                    # add other operators here - in descending order of precedence
                                    # http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm
                                    (mult_div_operator, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                    (plus_minus_operator, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                    (rel_comparison_operator, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                    (eq_comparison_operator, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                ]
                                )
```

Using runTests, we can try it out against a few test cases:

```
tests = """\
    cos(60)
    sqrt(1 - sin(60) * sin(60))
    divmod(a, 100)
    iif(iif(condition1,value1,value2)>iif(condition2,value1,value2),value3,value4)
    """
arith_expr.runTests(tests)
```

Prints:

```
cos(60)
[['cos', [60]]]
[0]:
  ['cos', [60]]
  [0]:
    cos
  [1]:
    [60]


sqrt(1 - sin(60) * sin(60))
[['sqrt', [[1, '-', [['sin', [60]], '*', ['sin', [60]]]]]]]
[0]:
  ['sqrt', [[1, '-', [['sin', [60]], '*', ['sin', [60]]]]]]
  [0]:
    sqrt
  [1]:
    [[1, '-', [['sin', [60]], '*', ['sin', [60]]]]]
    [0]:
      [1, '-', [['sin', [60]], '*', ['sin', [60]]]]
      [0]:
        1
      [1]:
        -
      [2]:
        [['sin', [60]], '*', ['sin', [60]]]
        [0]:
          ['sin', [60]]
          [0]:
            sin
          [1]:
            [60]
        [1]:
          *
        [2]:
          ['sin', [60]]
          [0]:
            sin
          [1]:
            [60]


divmod(a, 100)
[['divmod', ['a', 100]]]
[0]:
  ['divmod', ['a', 100]]
  [0]:
    divmod
  [1]:
    ['a', 100]


iif(iif(condition1,value1,value2)>iif(condition2,value1,value2),value3,value4)
[['iif', [[['iif', ['condition1', 'value1', 'value2']], '>', ['iif', ['condition2', 'value1', 'value2']]], 'value3', 'value4']]]
[0]:
  ['iif', [[['iif', ['condition1', 'value1', 'value2']], '>', ['iif', ['condition2', 'value1', 'value2']]], 'value3', 'value4']]
  [0]:
    iif
  [1]:
    [[['iif', ['condition1', 'value1', 'value2']], '>', ['iif', ['condition2', 'value1', 'value2']]], 'value3', 'value4']
    [0]:
      [['iif', ['condition1', 'value1', 'value2']], '>', ['iif', ['condition2', 'value1', 'value2']]]
      [0]:
        ['iif', ['condition1', 'value1', 'value2']]
        [0]:
          iif
        [1]:
          ['condition1', 'value1', 'value2']
      [1]:
        >
      [2]:
        ['iif', ['condition2', 'value1', 'value2']]
        [0]:
          iif
        [1]:
          ['condition2', 'value1', 'value2']
    [1]:
      value3
    [2]:
      value4
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. PaulMcG, your suggestion works like a charm, but I would like to know how can I fix it in order to use `iif` as keyword.

Comment: What would the syntax be if `iif` were a keyword instead of a function call? Have you written out a BNF for this language that you are constructing? That would be a big step toward deciding what should be a keyword, and how its respective syntax would work. Then write some sample code you would parse, and see if the BNF works with it, or has ambiguities. At that point, then converting to pyparsing, PLY, or some other package will be more straightforward.

Comment: the sintax will remain the same... your code allows me to enter `iff(...`, `iiiif(`... but it's ok. I can check the entered text right before giving it to the parser.

Comment: Do you also accept code like `x = iif(condition, true_value, false_value)`? If so, then I think `iif` really is more like a built-in function than a keyword. Again, your BNF and code examples will help you decide how to proceed. If you continue with this syntax, you should probably define `iif` as `Keyword("iif") + LPAREN + arith_expr + ',' + arith_expr + ',' + arith_expr + RPAREN` to enforce the use of it with exactly 3 arguments. And I think you *should* be able to parse functions like "iff" or "iiiif" - isn't it possible users would define a function with those names in their own code?]

Comment: This grammar doesn't use identifiers, due to in a previous step I get the identifiers and replace them with their value, so the grammar will only be mathematical operations with numbers and inline conditions. The only keyword I use is `iif`. The thing is the mathematical operations and the conditions can be nested.